# Issue with Spring boot configuration and configuration properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin

I have a class like below

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myConfig")
class MyConfig {
    lateinit var baseUrl: String
    var connectionTimeout: Int = 2000
    var defaultMaxHotels: Int = 10000
    var clientId: String = "my-domain"
    var applicationId: String = "my-app"
    var failureRateThreshold: Float = 20f
    var windowSize: Int = 100
    var minNumberOfCalls: Int = 100
    var waitDurationInOpenState: Long = 30_000

    @Bean
    fun myCircuitBreaker(): CircuitBreaker {

        var configuration = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom().failureRateThreshold(failureRateThreshold)
                            .slidingWindow(windowSize, minNumberOfCalls, CircuitBreakerConfig.SlidingWindowType.COUNT_BASED)
                            .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofMillis(waitDurationInOpenState))
                            .enableAutomaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpen()
                            .build()

        val registry = CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(configuration)
        return registry.circuitBreaker("my-cb")

    }
```

When I start my application it's giving an error saying

```
 An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Found @Configuration and @ConfigurationProperties on com.my.api.config.client.MyConfig.
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: try separating your `@Configuration` from `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: I want both in one file.

Answer (score 0):

`@Configuration` & `@ConfigurationProperties` both cannot apply to a type at the same time. However, you can achieve what you're trying for in the following two ways

#### Use `@ConfigurationProperties` on `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class

`application.properties`

```
config.circuit-breaker.connection-timeout=2000
config.circuit-breaker.clientId=clientId
```

`CircuitBreaker`

```java
public class CircuitBreaker {

    private int connectionTimeout;

    private String clientId;

    // no-args constructor

    // getters/setters
}
```

`CircuitBreakerConfiguration`

```java
@Configuration
public class CircuitBreakerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.circuit-breaker")
    public CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker() {

        return new CircuitBreaker();
    }
}
```

#### Separate `@ConfigurationProperties` & `@Configuration`

`application.properties`

```
config.circuit-breaker.connection-timeout=2000
config.circuit-breaker.clientId=clientId
```

`CircuitBreakerConfigurationProperties`

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.circuit-breaker")
public class CircuitBreakerConfigurationProperties {

    private int connectionTimeout;

    private String clientId;

    // no-args constructor

    // getters/setters
}
```

`CircuitBreaker`

```java
public class CircuitBreaker {

    private int connectionTimeout;

    private String clientId;

    // no-args constructor

    // getters/setters
}
```

`CircuitBreakerConfiguration`

```java
@Configuration
public class CircuitBreakerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker(
        CircuitBreakerConfigurationProperties circuitBreakerConfigurationProperties) {

        final CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = new CircuitBreaker();
        circuitBreaker.setClientId(circuitBreakerConfigurationProperties.getClientId());
        circuitBreaker
            .setConnectionTimeout(circuitBreakerConfigurationProperties.getConnectionTimeout());

        return circuitBreaker;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to do it by changing the spring-boot-starter-parent version to 2.2.0.RC1 from 2.2.0.M3.